# Why is a `switch` considered a looping structure for the purposes of `continue`?

Tags: php, loops, switch-statement

I just got bit by assuming the following:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  switch($key) {
    // ... some other cases
    default:
      continue;
      // ^== assumption: move on to the next iteration of the foreach
      //     actual PHP: treat this continue just like a break
  }
  // ...
}
```

But in fact, according to the [documentation for continue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php):

> the switch statement is considered a looping structure for the purposes of *continue*.

Is there a reason for this choice on the part of PHP language designers? As far as I can tell, `switch` *isn't* a looping control structure, so why treat it like one in this case?

Comment: One should avoid the use of words "reason" and "design" when talking about `php` ;)

Comment: you can use `continue 2` =)

Comment: I'm going to guess that treating `switch` like a looping structure provides some programmatic consistency to how `break` and `continue` work for **all** looping structures.

Comment: @zzzzBov: But if `switch` *isn't* a looping structure, why would it need to be consistent with looping structures. :-P

Comment: @drrcknlsn, `switch` would need to be consistent because it uses `break`, which jumps out of the active block. This is all speculation on my part, btw.

Comment: @zzzzBov we're talking about `continue`, which is used in looping structures to skip to the next iteration. It should ignore `switch`. `break` is OK in both, and should break out of the block or loop. Treating `switch` as a looping structure essentially makes `continue` synonymous to `break` in this use case.

Comment: @chesles, if you use `continue` on a block, it jumps out of the active block and *continues* on to the next iteration of that block. I can visualize `switch` as being a looping structure with exactly one iteration, which would make `continue` behave identically to `break`, finishing the loop and moving out of the block. I'm not defending the design of the language, I'm simply speculating on the pattern that I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you won't find any real "reason" for this behavior.

The only real motivation behind this behavior was probably that implementing `switch` as if it were a looping structure allows PHP to reuse existing `break` and `continue` semantics of loops instead of reimplementing a special version for `switch`.

Or to phrase it more positively: It's for consistency.

Comment: so, "they were lazy"? Makes sense, I guess :P

Comment: The `switch` expression is evaluated for each case (`case`, `default`) until the loop is finished (end of the code-block or until `break`, `continue` or `return` is given).

Comment: @hakre not true. "In a switch statement, the condition is evaluated only once and the result is compared to each case statement" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: I'm not sure about consistency, since it's inconsistent with, for example, switch/continue in C. However, after mucking around a little in the PHP sources, it does appear to be for simplicity in implementing `continue`. Since it is very closely related to `break`, which pays attention to switch blocks, `continue` also pays attention to them.

Answer (score 7):

The best explanation I can think of is that PHP considers it a looping structure so it fits the model of something that uses `continue` and `break`. The `switch` documentation doesn't shed much further light on it other than

> Note that unlike some other languages, the continue statement applies to switch and acts similar to break. If you have a switch inside a loop and wish to continue to the next iteration of the outer loop, use continue 2.

So perhaps it is because, like a loop, it stops the execution of the rest of the code in its structure.

However, when you use a number of levels, these two behave quite differently:

**`continue` without a level**

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    switch($i) {
        case 2:
            continue;
        default:
            echo $i, "\n";
    }
    echo "Finished with {$i}\n";
}
//0
//Finished with 0
//1
//Finished with 1
//Finished with 2
//3
//Finished with 3
//4
//Finished with 4
```

**`continue` with a level**

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    switch($i) {
        case 2:
            continue 2;
        default:
            echo $i, "\n";
    }
    echo "Finished with {$i}\n";
}
//0
//Finished with 0
//1
//Finished with 1
//3
//Finished with 3
//4
//Finished with 4
```

**`break` without a level**

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    switch($i) {
        case 2:
            break;
        default:
            echo $i, "\n";
    }
    echo "Finished with {$i}\n";
}
//0
//Finished with 0
//1
//Finished with 1
//Finished with 2
//3
//Finished with 3
//4
//Finished with 4
```

**`break` with a level**

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
    switch($i) {
        case 2:
            break 2;
        default:
            echo $i, "\n";
    }
    echo "Finished with {$i}\n";
}
//0
//Finished with 0
//1
//Finished with 1
```

Answer (score -2):

> As far as I can tell, `switch` isn't a looping control structure, so why treat it like one in this case?

Does one iteration not qualify as a loop? Same applies to `while` inside a `foreach` for example that only iterates once:

```
foreach (range(1,2) as $value)
{
    $i = 0;
    while (!$i++)
    {
       continue;
    }
    echo $value, "\n";
}
```

It does echo the values as well instead of `continue` the `foreach` loop; It is related to `while`.

If your expectation is that `switch` is like `if` (which it isn't), then you might not expect that behaviour of `continue`, however I'm pretty sure for `while` you expect it.

But if you really think that `if` is like `switch`, then how could `break` work differently than `continue`?

So I won't say it's that much out of order, it's just that `switch` is a control structure having the clothes of a loop. And as we normally use `break` (which you expect to work), the behaviour of `continue` is not that well known. And that's all. Or why would you expect `continue` to not work like `break` in a `switch`?

So the reason *might* be to have `break` and `continue` aligned.

Comment: My expectation *is* that switch is like a string of `if`/`else if`, which it is, unless I'm mistaken. Some languages that don't have `switch` (e.g. python) even say "use if/elif instead of switch". So how is switch not like an if in PHP?

Comment: "The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression." - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @chesles: Okay cool, that's what I assumed (having switch in the head as if if) - so the analogy is `break` and `continue` then. Do you expect them to work same as well (same like `if` and `switch` for `break` and `continue`)?

Comment: See my question, in which I describe the behavior I expect. Essentially I expect `continue` to continue the next iteration of the nearest loop, and I don't expect `switch` to be a loop, because it isn't, although PHP treats it like one for some reason. That reason is what I'm after here.

Comment: So what about `break`? What do you expect about `break` in `switch`? To break the nearest loop and you don't expect `switch` to be that loop, right? Keep in mind that any loop is a control structure as well.

Comment: Switch is similar to if/elseif with one major difference: if you don't have a break in a segment, code in the next segment will execute.  Switches provide a way to reduce code by allowing execution to "fall through".  Depending on who you talk to, this is good/bad design.  They are a different code concept and should be treated as such.  I hate PHP treats them as a loop for the purposes of "continue".  It's not a loop. It's not an if.  It's different.

Comment: @J.D.Pace: Yes, it's likely irritating, for example in C it is different and `continue` relates to control structures commonly more associated with looping. My dated answer here is likely a bit short as it has speculation inside and does not add any references why it was implemented this way in PHP or at least some more context.